# How can I set the working directory for only the job_start() process?

Tags: working-directory, job-control

I would like to set the working directory for the process started with `job_start()`.

The only way I know how to do this is to change Vim's current working directory before calling `job_start()`, and then change it back to what it was. That is a little bit of a hack, and I am afraid it could cause problems for some people. Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: There's also [this plugin](https://github.com/prabirshrestha/async.vim).

Comment: Note that still_dreaming_1 raised the issue in Vim's [tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1024).

Answer (score 2):

In Build-Tool-Wrapper, I've used `sh -c` to actually run `cd compdir && make args`:

```
" the a:cmd is managed elsewhere in the plugin
" it may contain many things, usually things like 
"    `cd build/dir && make tgt -j 8 2>&1 | gSTLfilt.pl`
if lh#os#OnDOSWindows() && &shell =~ 'cmd'
  let cmd = &shell . ' /C '.a:cmd
else
  let cmd = ['sh', '-c', a:cmd]
endif
let job = job_start(cmd,
      \ {
      \   'close_cb': ('CloseCB')
      \ , 'callback': ('CallbackCB')
      \ })
```

https://github.com/LucHermitte/vim-build-tools-wrapper/blob/job-compile/autoload/lh/btw/job_build.vim#L156

I haven't fully tested it yet on windows though.